# Getting crash when ice candidate delegate method called

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

[image]
**Please help what is the issue.???**

webrtc library calling some internal method and getting excess_bad. and crashed

If needed any more information plz ask.

**//code**

```
 let iceServer = RTCICEServer(uri:URL(string: resturi), username: “***”, password: “***”)

// Enable SSL globally for WebRTC in our app
let pcFactory:RTCPeerConnectionFactory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory()

let rtcConfiguration = RTCConfiguration()
rtcConfiguration.iceServers = [iceServer!]

let pair1 = RTCPair(key: "OfferToReceiveAudio", value: "true")
let pair2 = RTCPair(key: "OfferToReceiveVideo", value: "false")

let pair3 = RTCPair(key: "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", value: "true")

self.mediaConstraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [pair1!,pair2!], optionalConstraints:[pair3!])

 // Create the peer connection using the ICE server list and the current class as the delegate

    let localStream:RTCMediaStream = pcFactory.mediaStream(withLabel: “12345”)
    let audioTrack:RTCAudioTrack = pcFactory.audioTrack(withID: “123456”)
    audioTrack.delegate = self

    let status = localStream.addAudioTrack(audioTrack)

 self.peerConnection = pcFactory.peerConnection(with: rtcConfiguration, constraints: self.mediaConstraints!, delegate: self)

  let pstatus = self.peerConnection!.add(localStream)

  print(status)
  print(pstatus)

//Let’s look at how the offer is created, which initiates the call.
 self.peerConnection!.createOffer(with: self, constraints: self.mediaConstraints)
```

**I am getting sip here.**

```
public func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, didCreateSessionDescription sdp: RTCSessionDescription!, error: Error!)
```

**getting crash when this delegate called.**

```
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, gotICECandidate candidate: RTCICECandidate!)
```

**Crash Report**

> > Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x5000000000000038 Termination Signal:
> >     Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
> >     Terminating Process: exc handler [0] Triggered by Thread:  9
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f58816c mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f587fdc mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000190585cec
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000190583908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001904b2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 5   GraphicsServices
>     0x0000000191f35198 GSEventRunModal + 180 6   UIKit
>     0x000000019648b818 -[UIApplication _run] + 684 7   UIKit
>     0x0000000196486550 UIApplicationMain + 208 8   Shukran
>     0x0000000100080a1c 0x10007c000 + 18972 9   libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018f4945b8 start + 4
>
> Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread Thread 1: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f58816c mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f587fdc mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000190585cec
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000190583908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001904b2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 5   Foundation
>
>     0x0000000190fc0b1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
>   6   Foundation                        0x0000000190fe160c
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 7   UIKit                          0x0000000196e00e6c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 8   Foundation 
>     0x00000001910be50c __NSThread__start** + 1024 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240
>   10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body +
>   0 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f668dbc thread_start +
>   4
>
> Thread 2 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread Thread 2: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f58816c mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f587fdc mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000190585cec
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000190583908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001904b2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 5   AVFAudio
>     0x00000001a9baafe8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 6
>   AVFAudio                          0x00000001a9bd0f14
>   CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 3: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f58816c mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f587fdc mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000190585cec
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000190583908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001904b2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 5   CFNetwork
>
>     0x0000000190c9fcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
>   336 6   Foundation                        0x00000001910be50c
>   __NSThread__start** + 1024 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f668db0
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f5a6a88
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018f669188 _pthread_wqthread + 968 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018f668db4 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f668db0
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f5a5e1c
>   __psynch_cvwait + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018f66a9d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 2   Shukran
>     0x000000010030009c 0x10007c000 + 2637980 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f5a623c
>   __select + 8 1   Shukran                          0x00000001003004d0 0x10007c000 + 2639056 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 9 name:  VoiceProcessThread Thread 9 Crashed: 0   Shukran
>     0x00000001001956ac 0x10007c000 + 1152684 1   Shukran
>     0x000000010019569c 0x10007c000 + 1152668 2   Shukran
>     0x0000000100168688 0x10007c000 + 968328 3   Shukran
>     0x0000000100191020 0x10007c000 + 1134624 4   Shukran
>     0x000000010033b1bc 0x10007c000 + 2879932 5   Shukran
>     0x00000001002d906c 0x10007c000 + 2478188 6   Shukran
>     0x00000001002d8670 0x10007c000 + 2475632 7   Shukran
>     0x00000001002ca330 0x10007c000 + 2417456 8   Shukran
>     0x00000001004293f0 0x10007c000 + 3855344 9   Shukran
>     0x00000001002fb010 0x10007c000 + 2617360 10  Shukran
>     0x00000001002faf94 0x10007c000 + 2617236 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 10 name:  PacerThread Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x000000018f5a5e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66a9d0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 2   Shukran
>     0x000000010028548c 0x10007c000 + 2135180 3   Shukran
>     0x00000001002f7544 0x10007c000 + 2602308 4   Shukran
>     0x00000001004294f0 0x10007c000 + 3855600 5   Shukran
>     0x00000001002fb010 0x10007c000 + 2617360 6   Shukran
>     0x00000001002faf94 0x10007c000 + 2617236 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 11 name:  ModuleProcessThread Thread 11: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018f5a5e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018f66a9d0
>   _pthread_cond_wait + 640 2   Shukran                          0x000000010028548c 0x10007c000 + 2135180 3   Shukran
>     0x00000001002f7544 0x10007c000 + 2602308 4   Shukran
>     0x00000001004294f0 0x10007c000 + 3855600 5   Shukran
>     0x00000001002fb010 0x10007c000 + 2617360 6   Shukran
>     0x00000001002faf94 0x10007c000 + 2617236 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 
>     0x000000018f66b860 _pthread_body + 240 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f66b770 _pthread_body + 0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018f668dbc thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 9 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x000000010303c100   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001024694e8
>       x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x000000016e54a45c
>       x8: 0x5000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000000016e54b818  x11: 0x0000000000000000    x12: 0x03e0fe0003e0fe00
>   x13: 0x000000018f66b770  x14: 0x000000018f668dbc  x15:
>   0x0000000000000010    x16: 0x000000018f669ab8  x17: 0x0000000000000001
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000004    x20:
>   0x0000000104082e00  x21: 0x00000001702a42c0  x22: 0x000000016e54a278 
>   x23: 0x00000001702a42e8    x24: 0x000000016e54a240  x25:
>   0x00000001702a42c8  x26: 0x00000001702a42e0  x27: 0xd96031967698005a
>   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016e54a1f0   lr:
>   0x000000010019569c
>       sp: 0x000000016e549b10   pc: 0x00000001001956ac cpsr: 0x60000000

Comment: show some code please.

Comment: which line  of code gives error?

Comment: @Mr. UB Getting crash at thread 9. Voice Process thread. stop here and delegate method called ice gathering candidates.

Comment: got any success? I also have the same. my app crashes while calling gotICECandidate but with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `iceServer` is Running fine or not, I have used Following `iceServers` and resolved the crash. Or you can build your own `STUN server`. It may be one of reason you are getting the crash.

```
let iceServer1:RTCICEServer = RTCICEServer.init(uri: URL.init(string: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"), username: "", password: "")
```

OR

```
let iceServer2:RTCICEServer = RTCICEServer.init(uri: URL.init(string: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca"), username: "webrtc@live.com", password: "muazkh")
```